# Android Studio can't detect a valid JDK?

Tags: java, android-studio, installation

I am trying to install Android Studio on my computer, but I am getting a message shown  [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpSAe.png). I have downloaded Open JDK 1.8.0 from here: https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild. I have correctly set the environment variables and even I can write Java programs in Eclipse. Could you offer me a solution. My operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: I believe android studio needs oracle JDK.

Comment: Use Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK

Comment: The problem is that I can't install Oracle JDK. I have asked a question about that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182295/android-studio-cant-detect-a-valid-jdk?noredirect=1#).